# The module has not been deployed

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

i am developping a project using [netbeans+glassfish], base on Java EE Web Application (JSP-Servlet, EJB, JPA),java database based on Djerby,The problem that it can't be deployed when i run it.
And when i remove the annotation @PersistenceContext the deployment works
, but  need to put that annotation .

here are some exception:

```
In-place deployment at C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\web
GlassFish Server (1), deploy, null, false
C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

#### Netbeans Log

```
 C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
    Created dir: C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\web\META-INF
    Copying 1 file to C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\web\META-INF
    Created dir: C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF
    Copying 1 file to C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF
    Copying 3 files to C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\web
    library-inclusion-in-archive:
    library-inclusion-in-manifest:
    Created dir: C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\empty
    Created dir: C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
    Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
    Note: C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\src\java\test\StudentDao.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    compile:
    compile-jsps:
    Created dir: C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\dist
    Building jar: C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\dist\WebApplication6.war
    do-dist:
    dist:
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

#### Glassfish Log

```
Avertissement:   RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool { PoolInfo : (name=java:app/derby_net_Student_Pool), (applicationName=WebApplication6) }. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
Avertissement:   RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ { PoolInfo : (name=java:app/derby_net_Student_Pool), (applicationName=WebApplication6) } ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
Avertissement:   RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.]
Grave:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:114)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.BasicClientDataSource40.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:117)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: ERROR 08001: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.checkUserLength(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.checkUser(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.checkUserPassword(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.BasicClientDataSource40.getConnectionX(Unknown Source)
    ... 74 more

Grave:   Exception while deploying the app [WebApplication6]
Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Grave:   Exception while deploying the app [WebApplication6] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: La longueur de l'ID utilisateur (0) se situe hors de la plage comprise entre 1 et 255.
Error Code: 0
Avertissement
```

#### Entity bean(Student.java)

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author ahmed
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByStudentid", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.studentid = :studentid")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByName", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findBySecondname", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.secondname = :secondname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByYearlevel", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.yearlevel = :yearlevel")})
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "STUDENTID")
    private Integer studentid;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "SECONDNAME")
    private String secondname;
    @Column(name = "YEARLEVEL")
    private Integer yearlevel;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(Integer studentid, String name, String secondname, Integer yearlevel) {
        this.studentid = studentid;
        this.name = name;
        this.secondname = secondname;
        this.yearlevel = yearlevel;
    }


    public Student(Integer studentid) {
        this.studentid = studentid;
    }

    public Integer getStudentid() {
        return studentid;
    }

    public void setStudentid(Integer studentid) {
        this.studentid = studentid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSecondname() {
        return secondname;
    }

    public void setSecondname(String secondname) {
        this.secondname = secondname;
    }

    public Integer getYearlevel() {
        return yearlevel;
    }

    public void setYearlevel(Integer yearlevel) {
        this.yearlevel = yearlevel;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (studentid != null ? studentid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Student)) {
            return false;
        }
        Student other = (Student) object;
        if ((this.studentid == null && other.studentid != null) || (this.studentid != null && !this.studentid.equals(other.studentid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "test.Student[ studentid=" + studentid + " ]";
    }

}
```

#### StudentDao.java

```
package test;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

/**
 *
 * @author ahmed
 */
@Stateless
public class StudentDao implements StudentDaoLocal {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em ;

    public StudentDao(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    @Override
    public void addStudent(Student student) {

        em.persist(student);
    }

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")

    @Override
    public void editStudent(Student student) {
      em.merge(student);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeStudent(int studentId) {
          Student NewStudent=em.find(Student.class, studentId);
          em.remove(NewStudent);
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudent(int studentId) {
          Student NewStudent=em.find(Student.class, studentId);
        return NewStudent;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> getAll() {
         return em.createNamedQuery("Student.findAll").getResultList();
    }
}
```

#### StudentLocal.java interface

```
package test;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Local;

/**
 *
 * @author ahmed
 */
@Local
public interface StudentDaoLocal {
    void addStudent(Student student);

    void editStudent(Student student);

    void removeStudent(int studentId);

    Student getStudent(int studentId);

    List<Student> getAll();
}
```

#### New Servlet.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author ahmed
 */

@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private StudentDaoLocal studentDao;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        String studentStr = request.getParameter("studentId");
        String firstname =  request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
        String yearlevel = request.getParameter("yearlevel");

        if(action!=null && studentStr !=null && firstname!=null && lastname!=null && yearlevel!=null ){

      int id=Integer.parseInt(studentStr);
         int year = Integer.parseInt(yearlevel);
        request.setAttribute("year", year);
        request.setAttribute("id", id);
        request.setAttribute("n", firstname);
        request.setAttribute("s", lastname);
          Student s = new Student();

       studentDao.addStudent(s);
        //Student s=new Student(id,firstname,lastname,year);

         }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("student.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: Read the error message. It tells you that the problem is with connecting to the database, due to an invalid user name (which apparently is empty)

Comment: Normally , i'm connected to database , i don't know why he is showing that error ... take a look here plz : http://i.imgur.com/1XM7K91.png
I alreday worked with the database with some jsf project

Comment: That is your persistence.xml. The problem sems to be in the database pool definition inside your glassfish server: *RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool { PoolInfo : (name=java:app/derby_net_Student_Pool)*

Comment: and how to correct the problém?, by the way i did not create any pool before , think i'm using the default one provided by glassfish

Comment: I don't know that. I can read error messages, but I've never used Glassfish nor Derby. Read the documentation?

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate y'r help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are using [Payara](http://www.payara.fish/) as your application server, instead of Glassfish which is updated and patched version of Glassfish. Glassfish is not maintained and some versions like 4.1 contain bugs that will not be fixed - like the one with resource creation which can also be source of your problem.

Second, check your persistence.xml file and make sure you have correct JTA persitence name, the same as the datasource JNDI name on your Glassfish/Payara server: `<jta-data-source>YOURDSNAMEHERE</jta-data-source>`.

Third, go to Glassfish/Payara administration and check that you have JDBC connection pool and JDBC resource correctly set up and named -> [instructions](http://blog.payara.fish/an-introduction-to-connection-pools-in-payara-server)

Test your JDBC resource in the application server's administration console before proceeding and putting it in your persistence.xml, but most of all - make sure you switch to Payara instead of Glassfish to save your self from wasting time on possible bugs not fixed - they are basically the same thing, except that Payara is patched and actively maintained.

Comment: Good idea , i will try to switsh to Payara server ,thank you for the suggestion. By the way my problem has been solved , it was with the JDBC connection database pool definition inside  glassfish server , to perform the Injection Of Entitymanager and communicate finnaly with jdbc